# using HostListener in a structural directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a structural directive in which it's needed to listen to events on the host like it's done on an attribute directive.

There is no error in using `@HostListener` in the directive but no event is received.

Here is the directive code:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[myUnless]' })
export class UnlessDirective {

constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
    ) { }

@HostListener("click", ["$event"]) public onClick(event: any) {
        console.log("click", event);
}

@Input() set myUnless(condition: boolean) {
    if (!condition) {
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
    this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
}
}
```

and the template:

```
<h1>Structural Directive with HostListener</h1>


<p *myUnless="condition">
condition is false and myUnless is true.
</p>

<p *myUnless="!condition">
condition is true and myUnless is false.
</p>
```

There's also a [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/cf7yVoNmUU6lnVArKlse?p=preview)

The question is if it's possible to use `@HostListener` in structural directives?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`@HostListener` works but it's applied to comment html tag like:

```
<!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-my-unless": "true"
}-->
```

You can try the following workaround:

```typescript
@Directive({ selector: '[myUnless]' })
export class UnlessDirective {

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private renderer: Renderer) { }

  onClick(event: any) {
    console.log("click", event);
  }

  @Input() set myUnless(condition: boolean) {
    if (!condition) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);

      const el = this.templateRef.elementRef.nativeElement.nextElementSibling;
      this.renderer.listen(el, 'click', this.onClick);  
    } else {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FWOf0dy08kMLXPZIzfsv?p=preview)

Comment: so it's basically not working because it's connected to the template?

Comment: Yes, it's walks through `visitEmbeddedTemplate` (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.6/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/view_compiler/view_binder.ts#L94) There is no method `bindRenderOutputs` instead of within `visitElement` (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.6/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/view_compiler/view_binder.ts#L68) So `HostListener` has no effect in this case

Comment: you can get your `el` from the embeddedView that you just created: `var el = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef).rootNodes[0];`